# Fractional scaling, icons on desktop

Tags: display, icons, display-resolution, scaling

I have ubuntu 20.04 LTS. My laptop's display uses a resolution of 1920x1080.
When using fractional scaling 100%  everything is OK. When using fractional scaling of 125%, desktop icons scale wrong horizontally.[image] File Manager shows the icons correctly.

How to fix that?

Comment: I used to have this problem and the fix described here worked for me: [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232545/thumbnails-on-desktop-are-stretched-and-do-not-keep-aspect-ratio-of-original-thu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232545/thumbnails-on-desktop-are-stretched-and-do-not-keep-aspect-ratio-of-original-thu)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thumbnails on desktop are stretched and do not keep aspect ratio of original thumbnails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1232545/thumbnails-on-desktop-are-stretched-and-do-not-keep-aspect-ratio-of-original-thu)